# Why is one of my nut-clients not sending broadcast messages to all users?

Tags: nut

I have several clients connected to a server running nut-server. When the UPS goes to battery or back to line power all but one display broadcast messages like the following:

```
Broadcast message from nut@SERVER (somewhere) (Fri Mar 22 20:00:26 2024):      
                                                                               
UPS cyberpower1@SERVER on line power
```

I know the machine successfully connects to the server because it successfully shuts down when the UPS battery runs low. I also know that this user and console display broadcast messages because if I send a broadcast message using upssched.conf and the associated script I see the message displayed.

I don't seem to be able to change this behavior in nut.conf, upsmon.conf or upssched.conf.

Any ideas?